# MongoError: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Возникает ошибка

```
 MongoError: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument
```

Из-за чего она может быть?

Вот код запроса

```
const pipe = 

[{
    "$match": {
        "time": "2018.01",
        "comp": {
            "$in": ["100064", "100067", "100071", "100073", "100075", "100076", "100077", "100080", "100081", "100087", "100089", "100111", "100154", "100157", "100164", "100166", "100174", "100175", "100176", "100201", "100202", "100204", "101055", "101071"]
        }
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "comp": "$comp",
            "bpan": "$bpan"
        },
        "v05": {
            "$sum": "$v05"
        },
        "v04": {
            "$sum": "$v04"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "comp": "$_id.comp",
        "bpan": "$_id.bpan",
        "v05": 1,
        "v04": 1
    }
}]
```

А после вызова функции aggregate, выбрасывается исключение 
this.cube.collections.items.aggregate(pipe)

```
  MongoError: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument
        at Object.Future.wait (/home/manking/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.w9st7h.n6pbb++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15)
```

Comment: Наверное, неправильно запрос к БД делаете.

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-33393